# How do I make Owl Carousel have a pagination dot per item

Tags: javascript, jquery, pagination, owl-carousel

So for example if:

```
owl.owlCarousel({
    items: 3,
    navigation: false,
    navigationText: ["<img src='img/left.png'>",'<img src="img/right.png">'],
    slideSpeed: 300,
    paginationSpeed: 400,
    afterInit: afterOWLinit // do some work after OWL init
});
```

And if I had say 12 items in my carousel there would be 4 pagination dots. However, I wish to have 12 dots (1 for each item) there doesn't seem to be a way of selecting this as an option for the script?

Answer (score 0):

You have 4 pagination dots cause you're displaying 3 items on visible stage. If you change `items:3`to 1, then you'll have 12 dots and only one item which is visible at the same time.

The dots represent the number of "pages" which can be switched. It makes no sense to display one dot for each item if there are more than one visible at the same moment

Comment: Okay but I require 3 items per page and 12 dots. How can I achieve this?

Comment: If the first 3 items are displayed, what should happen if a user is clicking on the 2nd dot? (e.g.) The dots represent a navigation...

Comment: All the images shift along one, so on load:

12 1 2

Then when the 2nd dot is pressed:

1 2 3

3rd dot:

2 3 4

And so on...

Answer (score 0):

I just now ran into the same issue. This is how I fixed it;

In `owl.carousel.js`, ctr+f for `if (i % base.options.items === 0) {`

Change this line to `if (i % base.options.paginationItems === 0) {` then go down to the configs and below `items : 5,` add `paginationItems : 5,`

Now in your init script you can just set `paginationItems : 1` to have a button per image, or if you'd want something different like displaying 4 images but grouping them in one button per 2 you could set `items : 4` and `paginationItems : 2`.

Hope this helps you or at least someone else in the future

**Edit:**

You also have to change `if (index % base.options.items === 0 || index === lastItem) {` (line 315 in my `owl.carousel.js`) to `if (index % base.options.paginationItems === 0 || index === lastItem) {`